# My app is calling all TabBarView contents when I swipe

Tags: android, flutter, dart, tabs

I have an issue with my app, the thing is that I have an app with 3 tabs:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: _isLoading ? Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator()
          ) 
          : Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: Material (
              child: TabBar(
                tabs: <Tab>[
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.person)),
                ],
              ),
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                ProductListPage(),
                OrderPage(),
                InfoPage(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ), 
      onWillPop: onBackPressed
    );
  }
```

And in every children page, I implement `onInit` to load datas from Backend:

```
/* The exact same thing in ProductListPage, OrderPage and InfoPage */
@override
  void initState() {
    _isLoading = true;
    onInit().then((value) {
      print('initStateProductList');
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

But the issue is when I swipe page on `TabBarView`, I don't understand why, but sometimes when I swipe from first tab to tab 3, the app is calling `InitState` from tab 2:

[image: In this picture I swiped from Tab1 to Tab3]

The same thing when I swipe from Tab3 to Tab1, I found a workaround with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` but I don't like it because I want to reload everytime I swipe.

Answer (score 0):

you are implementing this on parent

```
_isLoading ? Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator()
          )
```

just leave it to your children this are the tab

```
 children: [
        ProductListPage(),
        OrderPage(),
        InfoPage(),
      ],
```